# OSGI MVC Web Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, osgi, web-frameworks

I am evaluating an architecture for a web application. We need to be able to update parts of our business objects and the front end also.

We have already made the choice to use the OSGi architectural patterns but have not found a good and consolidated framework.

I wonder if there is an MVC framework like Spring MVC that is 100% java with your views created using JSP tags and is OSGi ready.

Sorry for bad English.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're still evaluation an architecture I'm wondering if you really need an server side MVC framework. We are using JAX-RS in OSGi (using [Amdatu Web](http://amdatu.bitbucket.org/components/web.html)) on the server and AngularJS on the client. This works really well for modern web applications, unless you have some very specific reason to use a server side MVC framework.

To get an idea of a complete application there is a [demo project](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/showcase/src) available as well.

Comment: Hello Paul thanks for the reply, I need to be able to hot deploy eg including JSPs or htmls. Need to be done that way to get meet SLAs without wasting much time in the deploy.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. The html/JS is also packaged in a bundle, so you can update them the same way.

Comment: Hello Paul, I've been looking far deeper into the tip that sent me, Amdatu. Apparently he meets my expectations on modularity seeking to front-end to the back end as well. I'll take a apronfundada about security using AngularJS which is a framework that has interested me come to time and in this example he cited was clear the power he possesses. 

Thanks for your help and attention!